# How can I disable single-click to open on Pantheon/Elementary?

Tags: elementary-os, settings, file-manager, pantheon

Elementary's default file manager, Files, has single-click to open enabled by default. For those who prefer double-click  to open, how can this setting be disabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Freya, apparently installing Elementary Tweaks and changing the setting there works:

```
apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Then, access the Settings Menu and click on the Tweaks Icon.

[image: settings]
[image: tweak menu]

You can then toggle Single Click on/off as you like.

---

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, and the setting immediately toggled back on as soon as I exited the settings menu.

I had better luck with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences single-click false
```

Comment: `No such schema “org.pantheon.files.preferences”`

Answer (score 9):

Newer pantheon-files needs:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false
```

Comment: Working for Juno!

Comment: Just did that (installed on Manjaro) and it works. However, coming from OSX, I am wondering if it is possible to make it behave so that a single click on a folder (in column view) opens, but single clicks on files don't. Enjoying Linux immensely but still struggling to find a file management app that feels comfortable to me.